# How do I insert values when some of the columns are timestamps?

Tags: postgresql

I have follwing SQL-statement:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
user_id serial primary key,
username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
last_login TIMESTAMP
);
```

I want to insert my first row:

```
INSERT INTO account VALUES (
1, 'usernamehere', 'password123', 'admin@yahoo.com');
```

What do I type as the values for the created_on and last_login timestamp column?

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to [specify a valid timestamp literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT).

I prefer ANSI SQL literals, e.g.:

```
timestamp '2018-10-15 18:49:10'
```

which always uses the ISO timestamp format (that is yyyy-mm-dd and a 24 hour time notation).

Alternatively, in Postgres you can also cast a string that specifies the value in the ISO format to a timestamp: `'2018-10-15 18:49:10'::timestamp`

If you prefer other formats, you can use `to_timestamp` with a format mask, e.g:

```
to_timestamp('25.08.2018 21:34:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

To get the current date and time you can use `current_timestamp` (which is standard SQL) or `now()` (which is Postgres specific).

---

Unrelated, but: you shouldn't provide a value for the `user_id` column as that is auto-generated and by specifying a value manually, you make the underlying sequence get out-of-sync with the inserted values.

So you should use:

```
INSERT INTO account 
  (username, password, email, created_on )
VALUES 
  ('usernamehere', 'password123', 'admin@yahoo.com', current_timestamp);
```

Alternatively you *could* specify the `user_id` column, but use the `default` keyword instead:

```
INSERT INTO account 
  (user_id, username, password, email, created_on )
VALUES 
  (DEFAULT, 'usernamehere', 'password123', 'admin@yahoo.com', current_timestamp);
```

Or if you want a specific value for `created_on`:

```
INSERT INTO account 
  (username, password, email, created_on )
VALUES 
  ('usernamehere', 'password123', 'admin@yahoo.com', timestamp '2018-10-15 18:49:10');
```

Comment: you cought the unrelated part as well - n1 ;)

Comment: didn't know you could write `timestamp '2018-10-15 18:49:10'` in PostgreSQL i always do `'2018-10-15 18:49:10'::timestamp` when i need to.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The syntax `timestamp '2018-10-15 18:49:10'` is defined in the SQL standard and works in a variety of database products - that's why I prefer that. The cast using `::timestamp` is just as good, but Postgres specific

Comment: "The syntax timestamp '2018-10-15 18:49:10' is defined in the SQL standard and works in a variety of database products" Not all off us have a ANSI SQL standard copy at home.. But i assume this approach also works for other "casting types" like `int '1'` (bad example i know).. But thanks i learned something new today

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `now()`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO account VALUES (
1, 'usernamehere', 'password123', 'admin@yahoo.com', now(), now());
```

In case `last_login` should remain `NULL` use this query:

```
INSERT INTO account VALUES (
1, 'usernamehere', 'password123', 'admin@yahoo.com', now(), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you read the official [docs on date/time data-types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html) first.

PostgreSQL accepts several input formats for timestamp with time zone or timestamp in general - the output format depends on the DateStyle parameter.

You can use Javascript's [Date.now()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_now.asp) function, divide the result by 1000 and feed it to PostgreSQL's [to_timestamp(double precision)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.5.2.2.30.1.1) function.

That will always give you the correct value.

In your case:

```
INSERT INTO account (username, password, email, created_on, last_login) VALUES 
('usernamehere', 'password123', 'admin@yahoo.com', now(), NULL);
```

Please **NOTE**: When inserting a new row, you don't supply the id - it's of type serial and is auto-generated in a sequence for you..

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO account VALUES (
1, 'usernamehere', 'password123', 'admin@yahoo.com', now());
```

Last one can be `null`, if you wanna save that then pass it as `now()` as well